# Pass video uploaded via django to cv2

Tags: python, django, opencv

I am uploading video via django and want to process it using cv2.
This is how video uploaded via django is accessed.

```
video_obj = request.FILES['file_name']
```

Next i want to pass it to opencv. I dont want to save video in disk first and then acess it via cv2 using following code

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_path)
```

I tried passing this video_obj to VideoCapture this way

```
video_obj = request.FILES['file_name']
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_obj)
```

But i got following error

```
Can't convert object of type 'TemporaryUploadedFile' to 'str' for 'filename'
VideoCapture() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)
```

Comment: "I dont want to save video in disk first" -- you have to.

Comment: @berak cant we access directly from memory?

Comment: How exactly do you want to process the video?

Comment: @IainShelvington i want to convert video to frames (images)

Comment: What happens when you pass `cv2.VideoCapture(video_obj.temporary_file_path()) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [`cv2.VideoCapture` can only work with filepath](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html).
So to get the path from `TemporaryUploadedFile` object you can use [`temporary_file_path()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L64) method.

Answer (score 2):

[@Abdul Niyas P M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699447/abdul-niyas-p-m)'s answer is right but here's an example for people like me:

```py
video_obj = request.FILES['file_name']
vid_path = video_obj.temporary_file_path()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_path)
```